# Spring + Jetty: graceful shutdown

Tags: java, spring, jetty, embedded-jetty

Objective: Having Spring web application with an embedded Jetty, I'd like to shutdown/restart the application gracefully.
Here's the `EmbeddedServletContainerFactory` bean (I'll add the omitted code if needed):

```java
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory jettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
    JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    factory.addServerCustomizers(server -> {

        server.setStopAtShutdown(false);

        /*
         * StatisticsHandler has to be added for graceful shutdown to work (see
         * https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/1549#issuecomment-301102535)
         */
        StatisticsHandler statisticsHandler = new StatisticsHandler();
        statisticsHandler.setHandler(server.getHandler());
        server.setHandler(statisticsHandler);
    });
    return factory;
}
```

and here's our shutdown signal handler:

```java
@Component
public class ShutdownSignalHandler {

    @Value("${shutdown.signalType:TERM}")
    private String signal;

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    private Server jetty; 

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        Signal.handle(new Signal(signal), this::signalHandler);
    }

    private void signalHandler(Signal signal) {
        jetty.stop();
        context.close();
    }
}
```

Question: having the above configuration, every time I restart the application via `TERM` signal, I see a lot of `503` entries in `apache_access` log (almost all of them happen while `jetty.stop` is being executed).
Any idea how/why it happens and what the resolution is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why/how does it happen? Well it's the default behavior of Jetty:  First, Jetty close the network connectors to stop accepting new connections and then wait for active request to be process. But the catch is new requests might be sent to Jetty over already-established connections (those which are connected before shutdown process starts).
Solutions: Send retry response for new requests sent over open connections. We customized `StatisticsHandler` so that, during stop process instead of handling request with `503`, it handles them with `307 Connection: close, Location: <original-url>`.

UPDATE: what we did was to change the implementation of the `handle` method of the `StatisticsHandler` class (Look for `Change this line!` comment):

```java
@Override
public void handle(String path, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException
{
    ...
    try
    {
        Handler handler = getHandler();
        if (handler!=null && _shutdown.get()==null && isStarted())
            handler.handle(path, baseRequest, request, response);
        else if (baseRequest.isHandled())
        {
            if (_wrapWarning.compareAndSet(false,true))
                LOG.warn("Bad statistics configuration. Latencies will be incorrect in {}",this);
        }
        else
        {
            baseRequest.setHandled(true);
            response.sendError(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE_503); // Change this line!
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can publish your StatisticsHandler-customization here?

Comment: @MarkusSchulte I added the part needed to be modified. It's not something special. I just changed the line with what we wanted. Just a quick comment: I didn't try to extend it because of the complicated handling flow. I copied the whole code and changed the implementation.

Answer (score -2):

503 - Service Unavailable

Apache can't a get a response when proxying the request to the servlet container because, there is no servlet container listening on the host:port specified in the proxy configuration.

Comment: We don't have any Apache. Thanks.

Comment: I though you did since you mentioned "lot of 503 entries in apache_access log"

Comment: Well it's the name that Jetty log handler uses.